# Convert pyspark string column into new columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using databricks and have a spark dataframe as follows:

| data | ida | ids | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [{fname=name1, value=777.7777777}, {fname=name2, value=456.4564574683}, {fname=name3, value=123.52624767358654}, {fname=name4, value=1.76}] | hfhdj-345 | trhryr-365 | all |
| [{fname=name1, value=123.123123123}, {fname=name2, value=321.321321321}, {fname=name3, value=765.234234234}, {fname=name4, value=3.45}] | hfdfg-453 | trhret-123 | some |

I want to create new columns in the dataframe based on the fname in each dictionary (name1, name2, name3, name4 - each of these becomes a new column in the dataframe) and then the associated value being the data for that column.

I've tried various methods, such as converting the data into json, but I still cannot seem to get it to work.  I want to be able to do this using PySpark and then drop the data column as this will no longer be needed.

Comment: whats your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by converting the spark dataframe into a sql view and then running the sql code below.

First, create a view from the dataframe:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("view_df")
```

Then create a new spark dataframe using SQL:

```
new_df = spark.sql("""SELECT
ida,
ids,
mode,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, 'fname=name1, value=', -1), '}', 1) AS STRING) AS name1,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, 'fname=name2, value=', -1), '}', 1) AS STRING) AS name2,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, 'fname=name3, value=', -1), '}', 1) AS STRING) AS name3,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, 'fname=name4, value=', -1), '}', 1) AS STRING) AS name4
FROM view_df""")
```

Not the most efficient method, but results are exactly as I require them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a udf that collects the value for each key? For example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


@F.udf(FloatType())
def get_value_from_list(name: str, data_list: list[dict]) -> float:
    for item in data_list:
        if item["fname"] == name:
            return float(item['value'])
    return None

col_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']

for col in col_names:
    df = df.withColumn(col, get_value_from_list(F.lit(col), F.col("data")))
df = df.drop("data")
```

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to work at all

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JGW you would need to also import FloatType. 
`from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType` 
So @OriginalBBQSauce solution works too . The only criticism I would have is that because its a `python udf` its going to be much slower than any solution that includes native spark functions... So for big data its kinda inadvisable.